# How to send images without storing them onto a server?

Tags: android

Is it possible to send the image without storing it in server?
Or, if it is not possible, how to send the image to a chat application?

I tried with firebase storage, but it has storage limitation

Please help me. How to do that?

I am new to Android.

Comment: `is it possible to send the image without storing in server? `. Of course. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily send file directly from device to device via internet, without using any server or cloud service.

If you have issues with storage limitations you need to purchase more storage, obviosly.

If you want to use free solution, try to search for another storage providers with greater limits or deploy your own server on your own machine (which unfortunately can be quite hard)